# how to pass row values from a column based on bool value from several other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df :

```
df = data.frame("T" = c(1,2,3,5,1,3,2,5), "A" = c("0","0","1","1","0","1","0","1"), "B" = c("0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"))

df

  T  A  B
1 1  0  0
2 2  0  0
3 3  1  0
4 5  1  1
5 1  0  0
6 3  1  0
7 2  0  0
8 5  1  1
```

Column A & B were the results of as follow:

```
df['A'] = [int(x) for x in total_df["T"] >= 3]
df['B'] = [int(x) for x in total_df["T"] >= 5]
```

I have a data spilt

```
train_size = 0.6
training = df.head(int(train_size * df.shape[0]))
test = df.tail(int((1 - train_size) * df.shape[0]))
```

Here is the question:

How can I pass row values from "T" to a list called 'tr_return' from 'training' where  both columns "A" & "B" are == 1?

I tried this:

```
tr_returns = training[training['A' and 'B'] == 1]['T'] or
tr_returns = training[training['A'] == 1 and training['B'] == 1]['T']
```

But neither one works :( Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use `&` instead of `and`: `training[(training.A == 1) & (training.B == 1)]`

Comment: `training[training[['A', 'B']].all(axis=1)]['T']`

Comment: Thank you, so far neither solution is working :(

Comment: check what types of data you have for each column, also what type of error do you have ?